# Can a noun participle be in the past? [Beiza 7b]

Tags: grammar-dikduk, tractate-beitza

the second part of the mishna in Beiza says:

> השוחט חיה ועוף ביום טוב, בית שמאי אומרים: יחפור בדקר ויכסה

How do you translate this? I would just translate: „someone who slaughters an animal and a bird on yom tov...“ Because השוחט is a participle with an article used as a noun.

But the Gemara on 7b writes:

> השוחט דיעבד - אין, לכתחלה - לא

We speak about a case in post factum. How does the gemara come to this conclusion? It seems, that the gemara understands השוחט beeing in the past: Someone who has slaughtered... But can this be? Can a participle be in the past?

Now the Artscroll commentary says, that if the mishna would speak about a case לכתחילה it would write:

> שוחט אדם חיה ועוף ביום טוב

So the difference between them is only the article. But does the article change the time? I am a bit confused by that :)

Comment: It is the idiomatic usage. English would have used *One who slaughters without having prepared the dirt to cover the blood, Bais Shamai says he may dig in the pile and cover*

Answer (score 1):

With the article, it's "one who slaughters… should…". As in English, this is grammatically present tense but refers to an action completed. In particular, it doesn't imply that the slaughtering was permissible. Without the article, it's "one slaughters… [and should…]". Again present tense, but now it signifies permissibility by stating generally that one does the action.

Compare the English pair "One who squares both sides of an equation loses information about the sign of the expression" / "One squares both sides of the equation as part of solving for *x*".

(I can't cite a source for this answer. It stems from some years' study of *mishna* and *g'mara*.)

Comment: So both cases are in the present tense and there is no participle for the past tense?

Comment: @Itkind, yes, both are present (or present partciple / agent noun). There's generally no participle for the past, right, but I seem to recall seeing some rare cases where a past form had a definite article and the meaning of "one who <verb>ed". Perhaps see what Gesenius has to say. (I haven't.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understood this well, the difference between שוחט and השוחט lies in the letter ה.

שוחט אדם means "a person may slaughter", while השוחט means "one who slaughters" thus hinting at a case of דיעבד. If the Mishna would've said "a person may slaughter" there would be no room for doubt (that he is allowed to do it on Yom tov(, but since the Mishna chose to say "one who slaughters", the gemara deduces that it wants to convey that it is not to be done לכתחילה. But the word השוחט is not necessarily to be understood as a past tense (one who slaughter*ed*).